# Reporting Format add dynamic Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I have a gridview for reporting list my parent records are repeated, I want the repeated records stable and show its childs those are unique(Farm1,2,3,4,,,100).Please let me know how is it possible in gridview or i have use some diffrent way to print like last given format.

My Report Is like :

```
Circle|Division|Range|Block|Beat|FarmerName|CloneName|Demand|Supply
Circl1 Div1     R1    B1    Be1  Farm1      Udai      1204   1204
Circl1 Div1     R1    B1    Be1  Farm2      Udai      1204   1204
Circl1 Div1     R1    B1    Be1  Farm3      Udai      1204   1204
Circl1 Div1     R1    B1    Be1  Farm4      Udai      1204   1204
Circl1 Div1     R1    B1    Be2  Farm1      Udai      1204   1204
Circl1 Div1     R1    B1    Be2  Farm2      Udai      1204   1204
Circl1 Div1     R1    B1    Be2  Farm3      Udai      1204   1204
Circl1 Div1     R1    B1    Be2  Farm4      Udai      1204   1204
```

But i want to change the report format like :

```
FarmerName  |  CloneName  | Demand  |   Supply
Circl1->Div1->R1-> B1->Be1                 // this sub header stable and its records scroll
Farm1         Udai          1204        1204
Farm2         Udai          1204        1204
Farm3         Udai          1204        1204
......
......
Farm100       Udai          1204        1204   

Circl1->Div1->R1-> B1->Be2                 // this replace the upper subheader 
Farm1         Udai          1204        1204
Farm2         Udai          1204        1204
Farm3         Udai          1204        1204
......
......
,,,,,
Farm100       Udai          1204        1204
```

If i have use MVC tech. Is any way in MVC to format report like this ?

Comment: may be useful for you : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189621/Creating-an-expandable-master-details-table-jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use datatableJS with asp.net mvc with client side or server side processing. Its also providing a methods for attaching child rows to a parent row in the DataTable. This can be used to show additional information about a row etc..

You can visit: https://www.datatables.net  https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html